# Trying to build server side datatable from pdo query

Tags: javascript, php, datatables, server-side

I have to build a data table from server side because I have more than 200k rows, and I don't have the choice I need to make it from an execute statement like:

```
$result['draw']=1;
$temp = BD::query('SELECT * FROM `ersmessages` WHERE 1 LIMIT 10');
$result['recordsTotal'] = sizeof($temp);
$result['recordsFiltered'] = sizeof($temp);
$result['data'] = $temp;
```

But when I'm doing this that does not page my results and for 200k rows it's giving an error. If I limit the query that works but on one page.

My JS looks like:

```
 $('#tableAllMessages').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "paging": true,
        "searching": { "regex": true },
        "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"] ],
        "pageLength": 10,
        "ajax": "req/getAllMessages.php"
    } );
```

How should I proceed to have a paged data table with 200k rows? I can't obviously use the ssp.

Comment: I am not familiar with BD::query function, is this basically ``pdo->query()->fetchAll()`` or something else?

Comment: @Dimi `BD` might be the database class in this case, and query a function within that class maybe?

Comment: Based on task that you are trying to accomplish alone, you are expected to run into the following issues: Running out of memory while fetching results, slow performance with large offsets(DB server simply fetches offset+limit results from server, then discards offset and returns limit),  issues with PDO driver and buffered queries on some OS.

Comment: Sorry I forget to tell, yes the query is just a simple prepare then execute with the second parameter as the param of execute

Comment: @Dimi the datatable ServerSide is supposed to override thos problems, some people are using it for a million rows

Comment: @axelaxel yes, i am also referring to server side performance https://www.eversql.com/faster-pagination-in-mysql-why-order-by-with-limit-and-offset-is-slow/

Comment: @axelaxel to diagnose your issue, can you load chrome debugging tool and see what response you get for your ajax request? Additionally, try logging queries generated by your serverside php when request fails and see if those queries can run on server without any issues.

Comment: @Dimi i'll take a look thank you

Answer (score 0):

ok the problem has been solved, i needed to put the recordsTotal to my maximum(200k rows)  size and i needed to add an offset to the query, that way i am able to paginate my table.

```
$offset = $_REQUEST['start'];
$result['recordsTotal'] = 200000;
$query = BD::query('SELECT * FROM `ersmessages` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `idERSMessage` ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET '.intval($offset))
$result['data'] = $query;
$result['draw']=$_REQUEST['draw'];
```